# I am getting an import error when trying to install Kivy

Tags: python, windows, import, kivy

I am getting the error "Unable to import 'kivy' Pylint(E0401:import-error)" when I am trying to import it into a file using "import kivy".

I have installed kivy by using the command "pip install kivy", I checked my site-packages and have found it in my list but for whatever reason, i am unable to import it into a file. I'm not sure where to go next.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have two (or more) installations of Python on your computer.  pip installed kivy for one version of python, but you're using a different version of python to run the code.

Comment: Show us the full output of this command `pip --version` and also the full output of this python code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: The error mentions Pylint, so it's not clear if this error is actually from Python or not.  What exact command produced this error?

Comment: Does the same error happen when you actually run the code?

Comment: Atleast you must show the error. Without it, it would be very difficult to find a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,
`python -m pip uninstall kivy`

Then,
`python -m pip install kivy`

Otherwise try upgrading pip to the latest version and try above steps again.

**Note**
According to me, when I try to make an app in kivy, I import it like this,
Ex: `from kivy import app`